# Is this translation very loose for the word 生き甲斐?

Tags: orthography

I'm a fan of the Japanese concept of ikigai and finding my ikigai has been an important and rewarding journey for me and I'd like to get a very simple kanji tattoo of it but I wanted to make sure that a native reader would understand its meaning when reading it.

> 生き甲斐

is ikigai (reason for being) the first thing you understand when reading this?

Comment: 'Ikigai' is really not so much of a foreign concept as the people who like romanticize foreign words like 'nakama' would have you believe. It more or less simply means 'purpose in life'.

Answer (score 1):

理解できますよ。

例えば自分の子供や孫、登山や写真などの趣味、生き甲斐は人それぞれですね。

日本ではタトゥーは入れることは一般的にはあまり好まれません。

温泉など一部では入店を断られる場所もいくつかあります。